# Multivariable integration problem in Matlab

Tags: matlab, integral

I just want to evaluate an integral as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyEvj.gif)

The function `rho_delta` is defined as follows:

```
p = 3;
delta = 0.1;
A_p = 1/integral(@(s) exp(-s.^2),-p,p);
rho_delta = @(t) A_p*exp(-t.^2/delta^2)/delta;
```

I try to use `int` function to evaluate the symbolic expression of the integrand function, and than convert it to anonymous function. Finally, calculate it using the `integral` function, but it don't works.

Answer (score 0):

The following code can calculate this integral:

```
I = quadgk(@(t1) arrayfun(@(t1) quadgk(@(s) rho_delta(t1-s),1,1.1).*(E(t1)-quadgk(@(s) rho_delta(t1-s).*E(s),0,1)),t1),0.9,1);
```